# How to push an object into an array in vue

Tags: arrays, object, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to push a newly created object to an array. The array is defined as

`clientengagements: []`

The Object is

```
engagement: []
```

So I am using a v-for to iterate through each engagement belonging to a client in my clientengagements array. **Everything works fine until I submit a new engagement**. It changes my `clientengagements: []` array to only show the new object. Now if i refresh the page, the `clientengagements: []` will go back to the array with the newly added object plus the other objects that already existed which is what I want it to do..

This is the AddEngagement component script that I use to dispatch to the store

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['addEngagement']),

    addNewEngagement() {
      if(!this.engagement.return_type || !this.engagement.year ) return;

      this.addEngagement({
        id: this.idForEngagement,
        client_id: this.client.id,
        return_type: this.engagement.return_type,
        year: this.engagement.year,
        assigned_to: this.engagement.assigned_to,
        status: this.engagement.status,
      })   
      .then(() => {
        this.engagement = "" 
        this.idForEngagement++
        this.$router.go(-1);
      })
    },
  },
```

The action in the store is defined like below

```
addEngagement(context, engagement) {
      axios.post(('/engagements'), {
        client_id: engagement.client_id,
        return_type: engagement.return_type,
        year: engagement.year,
        assigned_to: engagement.assigned_to,
        status: engagement.status,
        done: false
      })
      .then(response => {
        context.commit('getClientEngagements', response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    },
```

from there it should commit to the getClientEngagements() mutation which is where I believe I am running into my issue but I have not figured out how to resolve. Here is the code

```
getClientEngagements(state, clientengagements) {
      state.clientengagements = clientengagements;
    },
```

I have been recommended to use Vue.set() but I do not know how to apply it.. any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: When the application POSTs a new engagement to the API, does the API return the full list of all engagements? It looks like that's what the code assumes.

Comment: In order to use `.then()` on your action, it needs to **return** a promise. Put `return` in front of `axios.post(...`

Comment: @StephenThomas No it only returns the newly added engagement. I have changed a little bit of the code sense I posted this question

Answer (score 0):

So I have set the mutation getClientEngagements to use this now

```
getClientEngagements(state, engagement) {
      state.clientengagements.push(engagement)
    },
```

But by changing the mutation to this it has placed the already existing objects into a deeper nested array. see below

[image]

So the response.data for the new engagement only sends back from the backend that newly added engagement on the addEngagement action. is this a problem?

Comment: Is this an answer or an extension to your question? In a typical REST service, a POST request creates a new record and responds with the added data, not the whole list; that's what GET requests are for. But hey, it's your API, you have it respond with whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

```
.then(response => {
    ...// data transaction 
    context.commit('getClientEngagements', response.data)
})
```

Maybe you can do with the response data at first and then store it after that.

If the response data is an object, and you only want to store the value, 
you can do something similar to this:

```
for( p in object ){
    context.commit('getClientEngagements', object[p])
}
```

If the response data is an array, then you can try to use `for` to get the value you want and then push in the state. 
You should do the transaction of data according to your needs at first for your case.

Comment: for( p in object ){
context.commit('getClientEngagements', object[p])
} have you tried this , that is exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, but I actually ended up needing to add a extra mutation and use that as the commit, because I am defining to seperate lists of engagements. One for the client and one for all clients. here is the new mutation

```
addClientEngagement(state, engagement) {
      state.clientengagements.push(engagement)
    },
```

which I then use in my action here

```
addEngagement(context, engagement) {
      axios.post(('/engagements'), {
        client_id: engagement.client_id,
        return_type: engagement.return_type,
        year: engagement.year,
        assigned_to: engagement.assigned_to,
        status: engagement.status,
        done: false
      })
      .then(response => {
        context.commit('addClientEngagement', response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    },
```

and then this mutation happens

```
getClientEngagements(state, clientengagements) {
      state.clientengagements = clientengagements
    },
```

Previously it was using this mutation to add the engagement to the array which was why it was replacing the array with the new object. see below for old mutation

```
addEngagement(state, engagement) {
      state.engagements.push ({
        id: engagement.id,
        client_id: engagement.client_id,
        return_type: engagement.return_type,
        year: engagement.year,
        assigned_to: engagement.assigned_to,
        status: engagement.status,
        done: false
      })
    },
```

Hopefully I am making sense in my explanation